# Histogram's in Latex where my data can be generated using a computer code

Tags: pstricks, charts, pst-plot

This here creates a histogram.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

\savedata{\data}[{{0.5,1},{1,7},{1.5,1},{2,3},{2.5,1},{3,2},{3.5,1}}]

\begin{document}

\psset{xunit = 2}
\begin{pspicture}(-0.23,-0.53)(4,7.5)
\listplot[
  plotstyle = bar,
  barwidth = 0.8,
  linecolor = red,
  fillstyle = solid,
  fillcolor = blue!70
]{\data}
\psaxes[
  Dx = 0.5,
  xticksize = -4pt 0
]{->}(4,7.5)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

I am looking for something similar to this, except I want to import a data file I have created.
I don't know how to alter it so that it would plot the points for a data file I have created.

In my data file there is a list of number from -40 to 40 ( x- values) and the corresponding y-values are the values of how many times a certain x - value occurs.
So, an example of a data file would be.

> (-40,0) (-39,0) (-38,0) (-37,0) (-36,0) (-35,0) (-34,0) (-33,0)
>   (-32,0) (-31,0) (-30,0) (-29,0) (-28,0) (-27,0) (-26,0) (-25,0)
>   (-24,0) (-23,0) (-22,0) (-21,0) (-20,0) (-19,0) (-18,0) (-17,0)
>   (-16,0) (-15,0) (-14,1) (-13,0) (-12,2) (-11,0) (-10,4) (-9,0) (-8,6)
>   (-7,0) (-6,8) (-5,0) (-4,13) (-3,0) (-2,9) (-1,0) (0,12) (1,0) (2,12)
>   (3,0) (4,7) (5,0) (6,11) (7,0) (8,7) (9,0) (10,2) (11,0) (12,3) (13,0)
>   (14,1) (15,0) (16,0) (17,0) (18,2) (19,0) (20,0) (21,0) (22,0) (23,0)
>   (24,0) (25,0) (26,0) (27,0) (28,0) (29,0) (30,0) (31,0) (32,0) (33,0)
>   (34,0) (35,0) (36,0) (37,0) (38,0) (39,0) (40,0)

Also, I write this in LaTeX, and then I show it in dvi, but after I need to convert it to PDF.

Will this be possible?

The PDF part is the important part I don't much care if the graph doesn't show up in the dvi file.

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?
Any help would be great, Thanks

Comment: So you don't want to use `pgfplots`?

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't really care what I use as long as it will convert to PDF and print out correctly.

Comment: @HarishKumar Could you suggest a method?

Comment: @egreg I have added an answer but not sure how far it will be useful to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Your data file has some weird format. Generally the automatically generated data will be two column data separated by tab/semicolon/space etc. In this particular case you can simply copy paste the data as in this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      \addplot+[ycomb] coordinates {%
        (-40,0) (-39,0) (-38,0) (-37,0) (-36,0) (-35,0) (-34,0) (-33,0) (-32,0) (-31,0) (-30,0) (-29,0)
        (-28,0) (-27,0) (-26,0) (-25,0) (-24,0) (-23,0) (-22,0) (-21,0) (-20,0) (-19,0) (-18,0) (-17,0)
        (-16,0) (-15,0) (-14,1) (-13,0) (-12,2) (-11,0) (-10,4) (-9,0) (-8,6) (-7,0) (-6,8) (-5,0)
        (-4,13) (-3,0) (-2,9) (-1,0) (0,12) (1,0) (2,12) (3,0) (4,7) (5,0) (6,11) (7,0) (8,7) (9,0)
        (10,2) (11,0) (12,3) (13,0) (14,1) (15,0) (16,0) (17,0) (18,2) (19,0) (20,0) (21,0) (22,0)
        (23,0) (24,0) (25,0) (26,0) (27,0) (28,0) (29,0) (30,0) (31,0) (32,0) (33,0) (34,0) (35,0)
        (36,0) (37,0) (38,0) (39,0) (40,0)
};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Compile this with `pdflatex` to get a pdf file. Change `ycomb` with `ybar` if you want bar graph.

On the other hand if your data has this form:

```
  -40   0
  -39   0
  -38   0
  -37   0
  -36   0
  -35   0
  -34   0
  -33   0
  -32   4
  -31   0
  -30   0
  -29   6
  -28   0
  -27   0
  -26   9
  -25   0
  -24   0
  -23   0
  -22   0
  -21   2
  -20   0
  -19   0
```

saved in a file called `mydata.txt` then you can read that file in the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\usepackage{filecontents}    % just for demo
\begin{filecontents*}{mydata.txt}   %% to create the file mydata.txt, just for demo
  -40   0
  -39   0
  -38   0
  -37   0
  -36   0
  -35   0
  -34   0
  -33   0
  -32   4
  -31   0
  -30   0
  -29   6
  -28   0
  -27   0
  -26   9
  -25   0
  -24   0
  -23   0
  -22   0
  -21   2
  -20   0
  -19   0
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ybar]
      \addplot table[x index=0,y index=1] {mydata.txt};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mydata.dat}% external data in file madata.dat
(-40,0) (-39,0) (-38,0) (-37,0) (-36,0) (-35,0) (-34,0) (-33,0) (-32,0) (-31,0) (-30,0) 
(-29,0) (-28,0) (-27,0) (-26,0) (-25,0) (-24,0) (-23,0) (-22,0) (-21,0) (-20,0) (-19,0) 
(-18,0) (-17,0) (-16,0) (-15,0) (-14,1) (-13,0) (-12,2) (-11,0) (-10,4) (-9,0) (-8,6) 
(-7,0) (-6,8) (-5,0) (-4,13) (-3,0) (-2,9) (-1,0) (0,12) (1,0) (2,12) (3,0) (4,7) (5,0) 
(6,11) (7,0) (8,7) (9,0) (10,2) (11,0) (12,3) (13,0) (14,1) (15,0) (16,0) (17,0) (18,2) 
(19,0) (20,0) (21,0) (22,0) (23,0) (24,0) (25,0) (26,0) (27,0) (28,0) (29,0) (30,0) 
(31,0) (32,0) (33,0) (34,0) (35,0) (36,0) (37,0) (38,0) (39,0) (40,0)
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\psset{xunit=0.15,yunit=0.75}
\readdata\data{mydata.dat}
\noindent
\begin{pspicture}(-45,-1)(45,14)
\listplot[plotstyle=bar,barwidth=0.3,
    linecolor=blue,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!40]{\data}
\psaxes[Dx=10,Ox=-40,ticksize = -4pt 0,
    linewidth=0.4pt]{->}(-40,0)(-42,-0.5)(42,13.5)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]